# React-hot-loader using craco

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, react-hot-loader

I've been trying to get react-hot-loader to work in my project and have got it setup according to the instructions in the [package readme](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader#react-hot-loader). The main difference is that I'm using craco in this project and so step 1 means I have added

```
    babel: {
      plugins: ["react-hot-loader/babel"],
    },
```

to my `craco.config.js`.

My root component is marked as hot-exported:

```
// ...
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader/root';
// ...

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback={loadingFB()}>
        <Provider store={userStore}>
          <ProvideAuth>
            <Router />
          </ProvideAuth>
        </Provider>
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}

export default hot(App);
```

I've got `import 'react-hot-loader';` first in my `index.js`

And finally I've installed `@hot-loader/react-dom` using the following yarn command:
`yarn add react-dom@npm:@hot-loader/react-dom`

I am currently not getting any warning/errors on compile or in the browser console. But when I refresh the page or manually try to go to any subpage by writing it's url I loose all state.

Anyone got any idea what's missing?

Answer (score 1):

You also need `craco-plugin-react-hot-reload` on devDependencies and a bit more plugin, resolve config on `craco.config.js`, here mine.

```
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin')
const reactHotReloadPlugin = require('craco-plugin-react-hot-reload')

module.exports = {
    plugins: [{
        plugin: reactHotReloadPlugin
    }],
    eslint: {
        enable: true
    },
    babel: {
        presets: [],
        plugins: [
            ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
            ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }],
            ["babel-plugin-styled-components", { "displayName": true }]
        ],
        loaderOptions: {},
        loaderOptions: (babelLoaderOptions, { env, paths }) => { return babelLoaderOptions; }
    },
    webpack: {
        configure: webpackConfig => ({
            ...webpackConfig,
            resolve: {
                alias: {
                    'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom'
                }
            },
            optimization: {
                ...webpackConfig.optimization, 
                minimize: false,
                minimizer: [
                    new TerserPlugin({
                        terserOptions: {
                            parse: {
                                ecma: 8,
                            },
                            compress: {
                                ecma: 5,
                                warnings: false,
                                comparisons: false,
                                inline: 2,
                                drop_console: false,
                            },
                            mangle: {
                                safari10: true,
                            },
                            output: {
                                ecma: 5,
                                comments: false,
                                ascii_only: true,
                            },
                        },
                        parallel: 2,
                        cache: false,
                        sourceMap: true,
                        extractComments: false,
                    }),
                ],
            },
        }),
    },
}
```